# How to round off by 0.5 on higher side in R

Tags: r

I'm trying to get round off of numbers by `0.5`. My data set is as below -

```
Wgt
0.160
0.522
0.174
0.765
1.246
2.893
```

the result i want to get by rounding of is

```
Round Wgt
0.5
1.0
0.5
1.0
1.5
3
```

Basically, ceiling of a number by `0.5` . Please help me with it.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Simply do this:

```
x <- c(0.16, 0.522, 0.174, 0.765, 1.246, 2.893)
y <- x * 2
z <- ceiling(y)
z / 2
```

This yields

```
0.5 1.0 0.5 1.0 1.5 3.0
```

Answer (score 4):

You can try out `plyr` library with the `round_any` function which can do exactly this.

```
> library(plyr)
> x <- c(0.16, 0.522, 0.174, 0.765, 1.246, 2.893)
> round_any(x, 0.5, f=ceiling)
[1] 0.5 1.0 0.5 1.0 1.5 3.0
```

Answer (score 0):

Couldn't find any explicit answer to this baked into R, but here's a quickie. I made a function called half_ceil that performed the behavior you wanted on one value then used sapply to apply it to a vector:

```
half_ceil = function(x){
  whole = ceiling(x)
  if(x >= whole - .5){
        return(whole)
  }
  return(whole - .5)
}
sapply(Wgt, half_ceil)
```

This will round values with a decimal of .5 up to the next integer rather than down, but you can keep these values at what they are simply by changing the greater than or equal to sign to a less than sign.